# Simple getJson causing me major headaches

Tags: facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api, getjson

I'm trying to grab some data from facebook, and since it is a pretty huge amount of requests I've created a php file that will output to a nice .html file once a day. the data comes back from facebook as json so I'm doing my best to maintain that, but I'm having trouble getting any values back after retrieving the valid JSON.

simplified code looks like this:

```
    var graphURL = "http://www.explorevictoria.dreamhosters.com/csv/graphdata.html";

    jQuery.getJSON(graphURL, function(data){
       $.each(data.item, function(){
           alert(this.id); 
        }) 

    });
```

I keep getting a mix of undefined, null, or broken javascript. So I turn to you oh stack overflow gurus. Is there a fundamental flaw in my procedure?

Comment: interestingly, as an interim measure I fetched the data through yahoo pipes and rendered it as a json feed and now it works, so perhaps it is what getJSON thinks it getting(html vs json header)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, your json is invalid. http://www.explorevictoria.dreamhosters.com/csv/graphdata.html just scroll down and you'll see text which is clearly just some loose html.
"item":
`<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
Invalid method in request<P>
</BODY></HTML>
, "item":<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
Invalid method in request<P>
</BODY></HTML>`

Comment: I noticed that while I was working on it yesterday and got rid of that problem. What you are saying is, my method is sound, I just need to use valid json and it should work?